# Select a subset of one list using another list in MySQL

Tags: mysql, list

I'm really new to mysql and I have a bit of complicated question. I have a table of firstname, lastname, username among other information. I queried my table for all usernames that have a specific attribute (E.g. admins) and put my results in a temporary table. I now would like to use my subset (admin) list and query against my original list to learn what other accounts these individuals might have. 
Where I struggle is to formulate my query to use the information of the subset to look for occurrences in the overall list (table). I tried something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM fulllist WHERE lastname LIKE lastname FROM adminlist;
```

But that seems not to work. I lack the understanding what functionality I should use to get this done. I would appreciate some pointers on how I can continue to figure this out and query my list appropriately. 
Thank you. John.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this, here's one option using `in`:

```
select * 
from fulllist 
where lastname in (select lastname from adminlist);
```

---

Just a note, you don't really need a temporary table for this sort of thing.  Just use the query you have in the subquery above.  Something like:

```
select * 
from fulllist 
where lastname in (
    select lastname 
    from fulllist
    where someattribute = 'Admin');
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. This has been hard on me to figure that our and it looks so simple and works. Here is a question that came up since I ran the query. I noticed that I get a lot more back than expected. could I query for two columns at a time. Like firstname and lastname?  SELECT * FROM fulllist where firstname, lastname in (select firstname, lastname from adminlist);

Comment: @JohnWalker -- not exactly sure what you're asking.  Are you just wanting `select * from yourtable where firstname = 'john' and lastname = 'smith'`?  Perhaps edit your question with sample data and expected results.

Comment: full list
---------------------------
firstname,lastname,username
john,walker,jwalker@abc.com
john,walker,A-jwalker@abc.com
john,doe,jdoe@abc.com
tom,doe,tdoe@abc.com
tom,doe,A-tdoe@abc.com
mary,doe,mdoe@abc.com

Comment: Adminlist
---------------------------
john,walker,A-jwalker@abc.com
tom,doe,A-tdoe@abc.com

Comment: My results look something like this, since I only query by lastname. 

Results:
---------------------------
firstname,lastname,username
john,walker,jwalker@abc.com
john,walker,A-jwalker@abc.com
john,doe,jdoe@abc.com
tom,doe,tdoe@abc.com
tom,doe,A-tdoe@abc.com
mary,doe,mdoe@abc.com

Comment: So I'm wondering if I can add the firstname to the statement like

But that didn;t work. Any pointers on how to add complexity and slim my out
put from the query?

Comment: I tried this but this seems to not work. 'select * 
from fulllist 
where firstname,lastname in (select firstname,lastname from adminlist);'